# compute gradient line of each pixel and find the intersection

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection

I compute the edge map of the image using Canny edge algorithm. Then, I want to compute the gradient line of each edge pixel (the line through the pixel that is parallel to the gradient) and find the intersection points of these lines.

I use Python OpenCV. How do I compute the gradient line of a pixel?

Comment: What is “the gradient line”? Is this a line perpendicular to the gradient? Parallel to the gradient?

Comment: @CrisLuengo the gradient line coincides with the gradient vector of the edge pixel and passes through the pixel.

Comment: The Canny algorithm computes the gradient. You can probably reuse that. Otherwise, use [Gaussian derivatives](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/22/) to compute the gradient vector for each pixel, which directly gives you all the information you need to determine the parameters of your lines.

Comment: @CrisLuengo if I apply Sobel operator such as img_sobelx = cv2.Sobel(grey_img,cv2.CV_16S,1,0,ksize=3)
img_sobely = cv2.Sobel(grey_img,cv2.CV_16S,0,1,ksize=3)
img_sobel = img_sobelx + img_sobely   how can I compute the gradient line.

Comment: img_sobelx and img_sobely would be the two components of the gradient vector. But you should really follow my advice and use Gaussian gradients, they produce a better approximation than Sobel.